# Extract substring based on regex to use in RDD.filter

Tags: regex, scala, match

I am trying to filter out rows of a text file whose second column value begins with words from a list.

I have the list such as:

```
val mylist = ["Inter", "Intra"]
```

If I have a row like:

```
Cricket Inter-house
```

`Inter` is in the list, so that row should get filtered out by the `RDD.filter` operation. I am using the following regex:

```
`[A-Za-z0-9]+`
```

I tried using `"""[A-Za-z0-9]+""".r` to extract the substring but the result is in a non empty iterator.

My question is how to access the above result in the filter operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to construct regular expression like `".* Inter.*".r` since `"""[A-Za-z0-9]+"""` matches any word. Here is some working example, hope it helps:

```
val mylist = List("Inter", "Intra")    
val textRdd = sc.parallelize(List("Cricket Inter-house", "Cricket Int-house", 
                                  "AAA BBB", "Cricket Intra-house"))

// map over my list to dynamically construct regular expressions and check if it is within 
// the text and use reduce to make sure none of the pattern exists in the text, you have to 
// call collect() to see the result or take(5) if you just want to see the first five results.

(textRdd.filter(text => mylist.map(word => !(".* " + word + ".*").r
                       .pattern.matcher(text).matches).reduce(_&&_)).collect())

// res1: Array[String] = Array(Cricket Int-house, AAA BBB)
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter` will remove anything for which the function passed to the `filter` method returns `true`. Thus, Regex isn't exactly what you want. Instead, let's develop a function that takes a row and compares it against a candidate string and returns `true` if the second column in that row starts with the candidate:

```
val filterFunction: (String, String) => Boolean =
  (row, candidate) => row.split(" ").tail.head.startsWith(candidate)
```

We can convince ourselves that this works pretty easily using a worksheet:

```
// Test data
val mylist = List("Inter", "Intra")
val file = List("Cricket Inter-house", "Boom Shakalaka")

filterFunction("Cricket Inter-house", "Inter")  // true
filterFunction("Cricket Inter-house", "Intra")  // false
filterFunction("Boom Shakalaka", "Inter")  // false
filterFunction("Boom Shakalaka", "Intra")  // false
```

Now all that remains is to utilize this function in the filter. Essentially, for every row, we want to test the filter against every line in our candidate list. That means taking the candidate list and 'folding left' to check every item on it against the function. If any candidate reports true, then we know that row should be filtered out of the final result:

```
val result = file.filter((row: String) => {
  !mylist.foldLeft(false)((x: Boolean, candidate: String) => {
    x || filterFunction(row, candidate)
  })
})

// result: List[String] = List(Boom Shakalaka)
```

The above can be a little dense to unpack. We are passing to the `filter` method a function that takes in a row and produces a boolean value. We want that value to be `true` if and only if the row does not match our criteria. We've already embedded our criteria in the `filterFunction`: we just need to run it against every combination of item in `mylist`.

To do this we use `foldLeft`, which takes a starting value (in this case `false`) and iteratively moves through the list, updating that starting value and returning the final result.

To 'update' that value we write a function that logically-ORs the starting value with the result of running our filter function against the row and the current item in `mylist`.